# need to show alert or confirm box from a modal dialog in IE10 Metro UI

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I have a modal dialog with a button to delete records. Before deleting i show java-script confirmation box on client side .This works fine in desktop mode of IE, but in metro mode of IE confirmation box doesn't show up.

Please find the sample code below . The name of the file is "a.html"

1.) Open this file in metro browser & and click "Show Confirm" link. it will show the confirm box.
2.) Now Click the "Open Window" link & click "Show Confirm" link in the popup window. The confirm box doesn't show.

```
<html>
<body>
 <a id='lnkwindow' href="#" onclick="window.showModalDialog('a.html');">Open window</a>
 <br/>
 <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('hello');">Show confirm</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```